# How to make choco install application so it shows in "Programs and Features"?

Tags: chocolatey

I'm installing [this .msi](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi) using chocolatey which will install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266), as I'm updating the [vcpython27](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vcpython27) nupkg.

When I run this command manually in a CMD.exe window, the installation shows up in "Programs and Features", as expected:

```
msiexec /i VCForPython27.msi /qn /norestart /l*v install.log
```

However, when run through `choco install <packagename>`, nothing shows up in "Programs and Features".

When looking at the `silentArgs` in [chocolateyinstall.ps1](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/vcpython27/blob/master/tools/chocolateyinstall.ps1), the `silentArgs` are set to:

```
/qn /norestart /l*v `"$env:TEMP\chocolatey\$($packageName)\$($packageName).MsiInstall.log`"
```

When searching regedit for "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7" after a regular msiexec installation from a CMD.exe prompt, I find the following keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Installer\Products\8A4152964845CF540BEAEBD27F7A8519
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-21-650255990-4017621559-2147617900-1000\Products\8A4152964845CF540BEAEBD27F7A8519\InstallProperties
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{692514A8-5484-45FC-B0AE-BE2DF7A75891}
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-650255990-4017621559-2147617900-1000\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Installer\Products\8A4152964845CF540BEAEBD27F7A8519
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-650255990-4017621559-2147617900-1000\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC
```

If I uninstall and then install via choco instead, I only find the following keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-650255990-4017621559-2147617900-1000\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC
```

I tried appending `ALLUSERS=1` to the `silentArgs`, but that doesn't do any difference.

This can all be tested right now, using the currently published version of `vcpython27`, which exhibits the same issue:

```
choco install vcpython27 -y
```

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

**How can I `choco install` and make this application show under "Programs and Features"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the following:

```
Install-ChocolateyPackage $packageName $fileType $silentArgs $url -validExitCodes $validExitCodes -checksum $checksum -checksumType $checksumType
```

...into:

```
Install-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
```

...made it show up in "Programs and Features" and it can now be uninstalled from there as well as via `choco uninstall vcpython27`.

I believe all of this was a result of me including `$fileType` as an argument, while this variable had never been defined. So, you would assume the installation should fail, but it didn't. So a [bug report](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/629) was also filed.

Comment: Although I haven't dug into this, I suspect that there is/was some escaping issue going on, which meant the silentargs where not being passed correctly to the install command, but when sent as a literal array, it worked.  This is a complete guess though. Glad to hear you got it working though!

Comment: It seems like the original choco install failed (a log would be helpful). The only way it wouldn't show up in Programs & Features is if the MSI failed. To be clear, Chocolatey doesn't manage applications registering with that system properly, that's the MSI's job. Chocolatey is "just" a wrapper around the MSI.